# Package Electron for os x

Tags: macos, package, electron, electron-packager

How can I test my program which runs on windows also on osx

This is now the start code for Windows

```
"package:electron": "electron-packager electron \"CICone NT\" --platform=win32 --arch=all --out=electron-package --overwrite"
```

With which code I can run it also on os x to run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to package for osx, just change `--platform=win32` to `--platform=darwin` like this:

```
"package:electron": "electron-packager electron \"CICone NT\" --platform=darwin --arch=all --out=electron-package --overwrite"
```